# Как узнать кнопку отправитель сигнала у которого нет текста через sender()?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qpushbutton, sender

Обычно я всегда пользовался примером для узнавания кнопки отправителя:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication

class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        btn1 = QPushButton("Button 1", self)
        btn1.move(30, 50)

        btn2 = QPushButton("Button 2", self)
        btn2.move(150, 50)

        btn1.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

        self.statusBar()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Event sender')
        self.show()


    def buttonClicked(self):

        sender = self.sender()
        print(sender)
        self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text() + ' was pressed')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Но у меня возникла такой вопрос, а если 
**`btn1 = QPushButton("", self)`** и **`btn1 = QPushButton("", self)`**, 
как понять какая из кнопок нажата?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **`objectName`** : QString
>
> Это свойство содержит имя этого объекта

Попробуйте так

```
import sys
#from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Event sender')
        self.statusBar()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        btn1 = QPushButton("", self, objectName='btn1')
        btn1.move(30, 50)

        btn2 = QPushButton("", self, objectName='btn2')
        btn2.move(150, 50)

        btn1.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        print(sender)
        self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.objectName() + ' was pressed')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное)

Comment: @Konstantin пожалуйста

Comment: @Konstantin если вас интересует как сделать тоже самое при наведении на кнопки - задайте новый вопрос.